# Getting data from json says undefined in discord.js

Tags: node.js, json, file, discord, discord.js

Heyo, I want to get a data from a json file but it says undefined.
This is my json file:

```
[
  {
    "channel": [
      "960229917264584736"
    ],
    "info": {
      "cooldown": 3000
    }
  },
  {
    "channel": [
      "960229880405053473"
    ],
    "info": {
      "cooldown": 6000
    }
  }
]
```

And here is how i'm trying to get it:

```
let channels = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./channels.json")); 
    console.log(channels.channel)
```

Thanks for helping^^

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want here. `channels` is an array, so `channels.channel` will be `undefined`. If you want to log an item in this array, you can do it by its index: `channels[0].channel` or `channels[1].channel`

Answer (score 1):

The error in the code comes down to the wrong mapping in JavaScript.

Note that in JavaScript code, `channels` corresponds to a JSON array with multiple channels, like this:

```
let channels = [{channel1}, {channel2}] // the file JSON is an array [{},{}]
```

So to access a channel you will need to go to the following path:

```
channels[0].channel // 0 can be replaced for any valid index number
// output: {"channel": ["960229917264584736"],"info": {"cooldown": 3000}}
```

To get a channel id:

```
channels[0].channel[0]
// output: "960229917264584736"
```